# Cinco siguientes términos primos java

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio con el siguiente enunciado:

> Hacer un programa que pida un número entero positivo por teclado y muestre a continuación los 5 números consecutivos a partir del número introducido. Al lado de cada número se debe indicar si se trata de un primo o no. 
>   Ejemplo:

```
Introduzca un número entero positivo: 17
17 es primo
18 no es primo
19 es primo
20 no es primo
21 no es primo
```

El código que tengo de momento es el siguiente y no sé por qué no funciona:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Por favor, introduzca un número entero positivo:");
int num = sc.nextInt();
boolean primo = true;
int m = num/2;
for (int j = num; j < num+5; j++) {
    if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
    System.out.println(num + " no es primo");
    } else {
        for (int i = 2; i < m; i++) {
            if (num%i == 0) {
                System.out.println(num + " no es primo");
                primo = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (primo == true) {
            System.out.println(num + " es primo");
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que me imprime es esto:

```
Por favor, introduzca un número entero positivo:7
7 es primo
7 es primo
7 es primo
7 es primo
7 es primo
```

Comment: Te falta incrementar num para comprobar los siguientes al que has introducido, como te ha dicho @Flowen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De primeras, necesitas un bucle de 5 como comentas, por lo que te lo modifico, no tienes que utilizar la variable num en esa primera parte para nada.

Necesitas poner `primo = true` cada vez que vayas a comprobar un número. De lo contrario, una vez tengas un número que no sea primo, haras `primo = false` y seguirá siéndolo para siempre.

Y por último, sumar la variable `num` para comprobar el siguiente número y no siempre el mismo.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Por favor, introduzca un número entero positivo:");
int num = sc.nextInt();
boolean primo = true;
int m = num/2;
for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) { //HACER UN LOOP DE 5
    if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
    System.out.println(num + " no es primo");
    } 
    else {
        primo = true; //AQUÍ ESTÁ LA MODIFICACIÓN
        for (int i = 2; i < m; i++) {
            if (num%i == 0) {
                System.out.println(num + " no es primo");
                primo = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (primo == true) {
            System.out.println(num + " es primo");
        }
    }
    num++; //SUMAR PARA COMPROBAR EL SIGUIENTE num
}
```